# Two Counts in a MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a mysql query which counts the rows in the table for pagination, but I also need to count and group by another column.

I can get the Query to group the records and show correct results, but it stops the pagination from working.

This is my Query

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) as num, 
   COUNT (search_term)  
FROM $tableName 
WHERE client_id = '{$client_id}' 
AND search_term IS NOT NULL 
AND search_term != '' 
GROUP BY search_term
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num1, COUNT (search_term) as num2  
FROM $tableName 
WHERE client_id = '{$client_id}' 
    AND search_term IS NOT NULL 
    AND search_term != '' 
GROUP BY search_term
LIMIT $page , $limit
```

And you need to give `$page` value as the current page number and `$limit` will be the limit that one page contains

Comment: You don't need `GROUP BY search_term` when you have used that field in the aggregate functions.

Comment: sorry thanks, it has two queries with the second giving the page value and limit